# How can I use variables with npm 7.x.x in package.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

I'd like to access keys in `directories` using npm script for it.

```json
  "directories": {
    "client": "client",
    "server": "server"
  },
  "scripts": { 
    "test:client": "npm run local-tests --prefix ./$npm_package_directories_client", 
  }
```

But after updating npm from 6.x.x to 7.5.x I'm not allowed to do that anymore.

How I can do that with the new npm?

Thanks

Comment: I can replicate this using `npm@6.14.11` and `npm@7.5.3`

Comment: Related? https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2609 https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2452

Comment: I think they've been removed https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/latest/implemented/0021-reduce-lifecycle-script-environment.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this problem is following:

```
"workspaces": [
   "workspace-a"
]
"scripts": { 
   "test:client": "npm run local-tests -w", 
}
```

see npm workspaces [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces)

Answer (score 6):

I could solve it by moving my *variables* under `"config": {…}`.

Like so:

```json
  "config": {
    "directories": {
      "client": "client",
      "server": "server"
    }
  },
  "scripts": { 
    "test:client": "npm run local-tests --prefix ./$npm_package_config_directories_client", 
  }
```

See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#config

Answer (score 0):

Same problem! Solved using your solution! Thanks mate! I suggest a nive way to add commentaries to our json files.

```
  "config": {
     "@comments devPath": "Path to build the develeping code.",
     "devPath": "../castorweb/src/dist/webapps/AQSAPP_TEMPLATE/tmp",
     "@comments prodPath": "Path to build the production code: When generating app versions",
     "prodPath": "../castorweb/src/dist/webapps/AQSAPP_TEMPLATE/dist"
  },
```